# TCP DUMP 4 lines I do not understand, please help?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I need support understanding these 4 lines. looks like tcp dump but I'm actully not understanding what exactly is happening here.

```
13:13:22.407445 IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: S 2910497703:2910497703(0)
  win 5840 <mss 1460,sackok,timestamp="" 518611="" 0,nop,wscale="" 6="">

13:13:22.407560 IP 192.168.246.13.80 > 192.168.246.128.54955: S 3762608065:3762608065(0)
  ack 2910497704 win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,wscale="" 0,nop,nop,timestamp="" 0="" 0,nop,nop,sackok="">

13:13:22.407963 IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: .
  ack 1 win 92 <nop,nop,timestamp 518611="" 0="">

13:13:22.408321 IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: R 1:1(0)
  ack 1 win 92 <nop,nop,timestamp 518611="" 0="">
```

Comment: ...two second of [Google fu](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&client=safari&rls=en&q=understanding+tcpdump) ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a successful three way handshake (SYN, SYN ACK, ACK).  And then an ungraceful connection closure sent by the client (R for Reset).

IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: **S** 2910497703:2910497703(0) win 5840
IP 192.168.246.13.80 > 192.168.246.128.54955: **S** 3762608065:3762608065(0) **ack** 2910497704 win 64240
IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: . **ack** 1 win 92
IP 192.168.246.128.54955 > 192.168.246.13.80: **R** 1:1(0) ack 1 win 92

*(I removed the timestamps so you could see it all on one line)*

This particular pattern often occurs when someone is scanning your environment for open ports.  Someone completed the three way handshake, noted that Port 80 was open on the Server (192.168.246.13), and then close the connection.  This method (actually completing the three way handshake) shows up less often on IDS/IPS monitoring systems than the traditional port scan pattern which just includes SYN, SYN ACK, RESET.